# OSX problem starting FTP from preferences

Tags: mac-osx, ftp, path, launchctl

When I try to enable the FTP service in the preferences (File Sharing->Options->Share Files and Folders Using FTP) the check box enables and then disables again.  The console is giving me the message :

```
16/04/2010 12:14:20 com.apple.coreservicesd[51] sh: launchctl: command not found
```

This indicates to me that it can't find the launchctl executable

launchctl is present in the folder /bin

/bin is set in the PATH variable for sh and bash shells and also in the ~/.MacOS/environment.plist

How can I fix this so that my preferences can find this so that I can enable the FTP service.

Edit: Following various suggestions, I have removed the environment.plist file from .MacOSX folder, run verify permissions / repair permissions from disk utility.  I have created another administrator user and tried starting it for that user.

The permissions for launchproxy is:

```
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    60032 25 Jul  2009 launchproxy
```

and running the command `/usr/libexec/launchproxy ftpd -l -n` gives me:

```
launchproxy[964]: launch_msg(CheckIn): Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions for `/bin/launchctl`, is it executable? I tried it quickly on my machine, and it works. It starts a process `/usr/libexec/launchproxy ftpd -l -n`. Maybe you should also check `/usr/libexec/launchproxy`'s permissions.

I'm using Snow Leopard, which version are you using?

Comment: Using Snow Leopard too

Comment: Checked the permissions (updated main question) and still not working.  Tried running the process directly (and with sudo) but still not working